# Fullcalendar listWeek click issues on iOS

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

When I use the "listWeek" as view on my fullcalendar, it doesn't fire the eventClick function (on mobile devices).

It works perfect on desktop, where I'm using the "agendaWeek" view.
Does anyone have experience with this problem and know how to fix it?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_ui/Touch_Support/ can I assume you're using fullCalendar 2.7 or above?

Comment: I'm using version 3.4.0

Comment: Ok good. can you show your code please. Have you tested on anything else than iOS?

Comment: It works perfect on desktop. The problem is just, that I can't activate "eventClick" event on mobile, when I've activated "listWeek" view

Comment: yes you've already said that. Your title mentions iOS specifically. Have you tested on any other mobile O/S? Can you show your code please?